# Sending Hex data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with some hardware that can be controlled via hex commands. I already have some snippets of Python code I use for telnet control of other devices that use ASCII commands.

How do I go about sending hex commands? For instance, how would I modify `skt.send('some ascii command\r')` with hex value, and what's the best data type for storing those values?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 2, use string literals:

```
skt.send('\x12\r')
```

In Python 3, use bytes literals or [`bytes.fromhex`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
skt.send(b'\x12\r')
skt.send(bytes.fromhex('12 0d'))
```

In either case, the [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#bytearray) type will probably be useful as it is a mutable (modifiable) type that you can construct with integers as well as a bytes literal:

```
skt.send(bytearray([0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05]))
```

Comment: So if need to store x02,x03,x00,x00,x05  and send that as one string what would that look like?

Comment: @user1124541 see `bytearray` example above.

Comment: skt.send(bytes.fromhex('02 03 00 00 05')) will do.

Comment: So if I'm trying to conform to this protocol Jill's example should work? It's not clear to me if I decide to use telnetlib instead can I still invoke the bytes.fromhex()  THis is the protocol I am trying to adhere to.   (*3) Checksum : "CKS" inscription
This is the value of the lower 8 bits of the results calculated in byte units from all of the data up to the
immediately preceding data.
Example)
20H 81H 01H 60H 01H 00H 03H
+ + + + + + = CKS
(*

Comment: Absolutely, you just need to decide whether bytes literals or `bytes.fromhex` is more readable in your case.

Comment: Gotcha. But the data that is sent would be identical regardless ow which one I used?

Comment: Yes. ヽ(*・ω・)ﾉ (this Japanese emoticon is just here to fool Stack Overflow's minimal limit of characters in commentaries, and so does this sentence).

Answer (score 3):

Under Python 3, you have the great `bytes.fromhex()` function as well.

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('AA 11 FE')
b'\xaa\x11\xfe'
>>> bytes.fromhex('AA11FE')
b'\xaa\x11\xfe'
```